# Jquery focus function did not work

Tags: php, jquery

I have problems with my blur function code.

Username filter should check if the username key in exist in database or not. 
if the username already exist, it will tell the user that the name already exist and focus on the text field.

If username not exist, it will proceed as usual.

The problem here is that, if username exist or not, it will always focus on the textbox. I have checked multiple times and I don't know what went wrong. I would really appreciate it a lot if someone could help me. thank you in advance.

Here is the jQuery code :

```
$('#username').blur(function(){
        var parms = 'input=' + $('#username').val();
        $.post('checkUserName.php', parms, function(data){
            // alert(data);
            if(data == 'OK') {
                $('#tickUserNameOK').show();
                document.getElementById("userexist").innerHTML=" ";

            } else {
                $('#tickUserNameOK').hide();
                document.getElementById("userexist").innerHTML="Username already exist";
                $('#username').focus();
            }

        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Can you show the html of the form? I think, there may be the problem with the selector or DOM

Comment: this is the html form for the username field


<div>
      <input class="inputt" name="username" type="text" id="username" size="50" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" required/></div>
      <img class ="tickInd" id="tickUserNameOK" src="../images/tickOK.png" width="20" height="20" >
      <p id="userexist"> </p>

Comment: update this $('#username').blur(function(){ with $(document).on('blur',''#username'',function(){

Comment: Can you provide me the your html code

Comment: Are you sure the return value of data is OK? Do not use alert because it also changs the focus; use the console output.

Answer (score 0):

You have done a mistake on the very first line. `.blur` is a method not an event so do this

```
$("#username").on('blur', function()
```

Comment: still not working. even when i key in a new username, it still focus on the username text field. It should only did that to username that exist in the db

Comment: The code you tried was not triggering the function. It triggers the function. and as you are saying that it always focusing, it means you have wrong return type. please console log the data to make sure you get 'OK' (case sensitive) from the php file.